# Get current sequence Id to store in other tables

Tags: java, oracle, sequence, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

We have multiple tables and all are related with first table's primary key (example: id). Id is configured as a sequence and while inserting data into to first table we are using `sequence.nextval` in the insert query. 
Now while inserting data to other tables, how to get current sequence value or current Id.

We have tried below options:

1. `sequence.currval`, directly in the insert statement
   2.`select sequence.currval from dual`

Above two options throwing error while using `getJdbcTemplate().update()`.

Could anyone please suggest how to get current sequence value to pass to other tables after inserting data into first table??

Comment: If you use nextval in the insert, you can use currval in subsequent statements in the same session. Using currval first, if that is what you are suggesting you did in the insert test, is not going to work. What errors are you getting with currval in later statements though? Are you maybe using multiple sessions for the related statements? (Which could give you FK issues too). Showing more of your code, and the errors, might give more of a clue about what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert the same id (which comes from a sequence) to different tables, simple get it form the first insert and use it in the other inserts.

```
PrepearedStatement stmt1 = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TABLE1 (id) VALUES(yoursequence.nextval)", Statemet.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
stmt1.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rs = stmt1.getGeneratedKeys();
rs.next();
long id = rs.getLong(1);
PrepearedStatement stmt2 = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TABLE2 (id) VALUES(?)");
stmt2.setLong(1,id);
stmt2.executeUpdate();
```